# Parallel copy and opencl kernel execution

Tags: opencl

I would like to implement an image filtering algorithm using OpenCL but the image size is very large (4096 x 4096). I understand that the copy time to the OpenCL device may take too long.

Do you think it makes sense to address this problem by using a parallel copy in combination with OpenCL kernel execution?

E.g., below is my approach:

1) Split the full image into 2 parts. 
2) Copy the first half to the device.
3) Execute the image filtering kernel on the device, then copy the 2nd half of the image to the device.
4) Block the kernel execution until the first half completes, then call the kernel again to process the 2nd part.
5) Block until the 2nd part finishes.

Best regards,

Comment: could you add some platform and hardware details?  What is the PCIe linkspeed, if any, between your device and image?  Also, an AMD APU can avoid completely the copy although it has less compute units - some embedded chips also have this well integrated like the APU.

Answer (score 0):

OpenCL thread of execution is completely independent to your application. So there is no need to "wait" after each call. Just flush all the order to OpenCL and it should schedule them properly.

The only need is to have 2 queues, in order to be able to run commands in parallel. So you will need a IO queue, and an execution queue. A single queue (even in out of order mode), can never run 2 operations in parallel.

Here you have one example approach with events, you can call clFlush() on the queues just after doing the enqueues in order to speed them up.

```
//Create 2 queues (at creation only!)
mQueueIO = cl::CommandQueue(context, device[0], 0);
mQueueRun = cl::CommandQueue(context, device[0], 0);


//Everytime you run your image filter
//Queue the 2 writes
cl::Event wev1; //Event to known when the write finishes
mQueueIO.enqueueWriteBuffer(ImageBufferCL, CL_FALSE, 0, size/2, imageCPU, NULL, &wev1);
cl::Event wev2; //Event to known when the write finishes
mQueueIO.enqueueWriteBuffer(ImageBufferCL, CL_FALSE, size/2, size/2, imageCPU+size/2, &wev2);


//Queue the 2 runs (with the proper dependency)
std::vector<cl::Event> wait; 
wait.push_back(wev1);
cl::Event ev1; //Event to track the finish of the run command
mQueueRun.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NDRange(0), cl::NDRange(size/2), cl::NDRange(localsize), &wait, &ev1);
wait[0] = wev2;
cl::Event ev2; //Event to track the finish of the run command
mQueueRun.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NDRange(size/2), cl::NDRange(size/2), cl::NDRange(localsize), &wait, &ev2);


//Read back the data when it has finished
std::vector<cl::Event> rev(2); 
wait[0] = ev1;
mQueueIO.enqueueReadBuffer(ImageBufferCL, CL_FALSE, 0, size/2, imageCPU, &wait, &rev[0]);
wait[0] = ev1;
mQueueIO.enqueueReadBuffer(ImageBufferCL, CL_FALSE, size/2, size/2, imageCPU + size/2, &wait, &rev[1]);
rev[0].wait();
rev[1].wait();
```

Notice how I create 2 events for writing, these are the wait events of the execution; and 2 events for execution that are the wait events for reading.
In the last part I create another 2 events for reading but they are not really needed, you can use a blocking read.

Answer (score 0):

Try using out of order queues - most implementation's hardware should support them.  You'll want to use the global offset parameter in your kernels along with global_id where applicable.  At some point you will get diminishing returns with a division strategy like this but there should exist a number such that you can get a good payoff in latency reduction - I would guess it's in [2, 100] is probably a good interval to brute force profile.  Be aware that only one kernel can write to a memory buffer at a time and make sure the input buffer is const (read-only).  Be aware that you must also merge the result from N buffer splits in one kernel to an output - this means you will effectively write all pixels twice to GDS. OpenCL 2.0 may be able to save us all these divided writes with it's image types, if you are able to use it.

```
cl::CommandQueue queue(context, device, CL_QUEUE_OUT_OF_ORDER_EXEC_MODE_ENABLE|CL_QUEUE_ON_DEVICE);

cl::Event last_event;
std::vector<Event> events;
std::vector<cl::Buffer> output_buffers;//initialize with however many splits you have, ensure there is at least enough for what is written and update the kernel perhaps to only write to it's relative region.

//you might approach finer granularity with even more splits
//just make sure the kernel is using the global offset - 
//in which case adjust this code into a loop
set_args(kernel, image_input, image_outputs[0]);
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NDRange(0, 0), cl::NDRange(cols * local_size[0], (rows/2) * local_size[0]), cl::NDRange(local_size[0], local_size[1]), &events, &last_event); events.push_back(last_event);
set_args(kernel, image_input, image_outputs[0]);
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(kernel, cl::NDRange(0, size/2 * local_size), cl::NDRange(cols * local_size[0], (size - size/2) * local_size[1]), cl::NDRange(local_size[0], local_size[1]), &events, &last_event); events.push_back(last_event);

set_args(merge_buffers_kernel, output_buffers...)
queue.enqueueNDRangeKernel(merge_buffers_kernel, NDRange(), NDRange(cols * local_size[0], rows * local_size[1])
cl::waitForEvents(events);
```

Comment: Don't bother with out-of-order command queues; most implementations don't support them. The method of overlapping compute and DMA is to use multiple command queues and events to synchronize.

Comment: @Dithermaster This is true on the Host side, but device side queues tend to have support if the hardware itself can support it (e.g. many asynchronous compute engines in AMD)  - the only official line I know of that doesn't support it is Altera's.  This is something that needs better documentation but Intel, AMD, and Nvidia should have it working and with an image that big, I wouldn't be surprised if he's using one of those.

Comment: From my point of view, OoO queues and multiples queues is the same. Events have to be used anyway. So why have everything in one single queue and risk the implementation limits the speed when you can have it in 2? BTW, last time I used nVIDIA OpenCL it supported out-of-order but it didn't allow 2 tasks to run concurrently, so the kernel and copy didn't overlap.

Comment: @DarkZeros it's the right tool for the job [tm] and we should use it on that premise. On NVidia, that is a limitation of the hardware and you would might face the same limitation w/ multiple queues/CUDA streams - if you look at recentish hardware it does clearly say it supports it in clinfo and if the hardware supports concurrent kernel execution, it should work - if it doesn't file a bug as they seem to care about bugs in their implementation. You can use multiple queues too but that's more difficult to manage across infrastructure than just correct usage of out of order queues and waitlists.